# Switch statements with Classes

Tags: c++

We are currently studying classes in my Computing Science class. Today, the teacher introduced us to Switch Statements and I had the following question which he wasn't sure of:

- Can switch statements be used alongside classes if we overload the == operator?

Comment: If you mean the condition it can be : any expression of integral or enumeration type, or of a class type contextually implicitly convertible to an integral or enumeration type, or a declaration of a single non-array variable of such type with a brace-or-equals initializer.
You can find the full description here (I have quoted from here): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Answer (score 3):

Exactly as you phrased the question: No. But it is possible to design a class that is compatible witch `switch`. This is an example using a barebones wrapper class for integers:

```
// Only possible in C++11 and newer.
class Integer
{
public:
    constexpr explicit Integer(int p) : m_payload(p) {}     // (1)
    constexpr operator int() const { return m_payload; }    // (2)

private:
    int m_payload;
};


int main()
{
    // For simplicity. This could be a user input or some other value
    // determined when running the program.
    Integer five(5);

    switch (five) {  // (4)
        case Integer(5):  // (3)
            return 0;
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}
```

I’m going to gloss over a lot of finer details. What the code does is this:

- The value evaluated by the `switch` – in this case `five` in line (4) – must be either an integer-like value or implicitly convertible to an integer-like value. That’s what the `operator int()` (2) does – it’s called a conversion operator.
- The `case`s of a switch must be constant integral expressions, i.e. they must must evaluate to an integer-like value and the evaluation must be possible at compile-time. To make line (3) work all of the following must be true:

  - An `Integer` object must be able to be created at compile-time. That is provided by the constexpr constructor in line (1). The `constexpr` is key here.
  - The object must be created with a value that’s actually known at compile time. That’s the literal `5` in line (3). You could not run your program, query the user for an integer and use that user input instead of the `5`. The compiler has no way to anticipate the user’s input, after all.
  - An `Integer` object must be implicitly convertible to an integer-like value *at compile time*. That’s provided by the `constexpr` in like (2).

To sum up: Yes, you can design your own classes to be compatible with `switch`. But rather severe restrictions apply, and it has nothing to do with `operator==()`.